# How to create a read-only server role on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions

I am granting the "View any database" permission when creating a new server role, but realized this permission only allows the user to view the system databases.

I am trying to create a server role that is read-only and can read any database.

Is there a way to create a user-defined server role to read user databases? Or do I have to do this through user mapping per user?

Answer (score 23):

Posting this as an answer just because it is too long for a comment, and because it *will* be relevant to other users pretty soon.

SQL Server 2014 adds some new server-level permissions that will assist with exactly this type of scenario - they were designed with auditing in mind, but this type of requirement seems to fit that bill as well. You could simply add the following two permissions to a server-level login:

```
CONNECT ANY DATABASE

SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES
```

The former, like it sounds, allows the login to connect to any database. The nice thing about this is that it will allow this even for databases that are created in the future (provided you don't set explicit deny, which is how you can protect certain user databases from logins that have this permission). The latter allows the login to perform read operations on any database they have access to - so they can `SELECT` from tables, views, UDFs etc. but they will not be able to perform any `UPDATE` operations (I haven't tested if this permission understands when a stored procedure performs DML). These work great in combination if you want to give a login wide-open read access to the entire server, or to be more fine-grained you can grant traditional `CONNECT` privileges to certain databases, and the `SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES` right will *only* function for those databases where the login has explicit access to.

The [2014 security changes are documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411%28v=sql.120%29.aspx#Security) - well, partially; they forgot about the database-level permission `ALTER ANY DATABASE EVENT SESSION` - though that's not relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for this extended answer for up coming servers. Being that this operation/check is at the server level. Are there any comments on if the DB Compatibility Level. So if the DB CL is 2012, will the 2014 feature still work?

Comment: @SnapJag Compatibility level does not have any bearing on security features, it is mostly about how T-SQL is parsed and how the optimizer generates query plans.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Do you know if there is a permission we can set on server-level roles to allow updates on any database too ? (sysadmin fixed role can for sure, but can we do it for a user defined server role ?)

Comment: @MaxiWheat No, can't think of any trivial way to do that, sorry.

Comment: FWIW this won't work for Azure SQL Database. 

GRANT CONNECT ANY DATABASE TO [NameOfUserOrGroup]

Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: @Dzejms Makes sense, but note that the question was about SQL Server 2012 specifically, not Azure SQL Database, and is about server roles, which isn't even a concept there. It also won't work in Amazon RDS (same reason) or Oracle (completely different syntax). :-)

Answer (score 8):

[There's no server-level 'read any database' permission](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx) and server-level roles [can't be granted database-level permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677610.aspx)

So yes, you will have to map users to databases individually. If you're using Active Directory, you can create a windows group, then give that group a login to SQL Server, then apply db_datareader in all databases for that group (you'll need to create users in each database though).