# Azure SQL Server grant read only access to all databases, including those created later

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

There is one Azure SQL Server which has 100+ databases. For auditing purposes a login is needed, that can read data (do `SELECT`) from all the database tables in that Azure SQL Server. Databases are added and removed on weekly basis.

SqlWorldWide gave [an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/265165/254275) to similar situation when using regular SQL Server, but unfortunately `GRANT CONNECT ANY DATABASE` etc. do not work with Azure SQL Server. Azure SQL Server has server roles **##MS_DatabaseConnector##** and **##MS_DefinitionReader##** that allow connecting to all the databases and list their tables, but those roles do not allow `SELECT` to be called on the tables.

What are the options for Azure SQL Server?

Comment: How are these databases created?  Through a script, visual studio project, restore, by hand?

Comment: @JonathanFite most of them are created / dropped via script, but there are also ones that have been manually created.